# Eilenberg-MacLane rings in algebraic K theory?

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Given any abelian group $G$ and a natural number $n$, is there always a ring (unital) whose algebraic K-groups are $K_i(R)=0, i\neq n$ and $K_n(R)=G$?